# Missing Values in Weka --

Tags: weka

I'm using adult data from UCI [Here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult), when I converted it to excel file ==> then import it in weka
weka didn't recognize the missing values (which tells Missing:0 (0%)) ,
but the adult data contains missing values with " ?" value...

I checked the value in weka it also contains " ?" so, how can I replace all " ?" to " " !!!

Comment: How did you solve your problem?
My text data also has missing values but weka shows it 0%.
In place of missing values, weka is taking 0.0 as the value :(

Answer (score 9):

I can say a method.

1. chose filter
2. chose unsupervised-attribute-ReplaceMissingValues
3. Apply

ReplaceMissingValues use 'mean' or 'median' instead of missing values.

Answer (score 5):

On explorer, in the preprocess tab, find filter and select choose. Then in the filter, expand filter, then supervised, then attribute. At the bottom, you will find an option "Replace missing value". Double click on that and then click apply. Voila! The missing values are replaced.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not convert to excel.
2. Open raw file in any text editor.
3. Replace all spaces with nothing (e.g. Ctrl-H in notepad).
4. Add header line.
5. Save as adult.csv (choose all files in file type drop-down list if in notepad)
6. Open in Weka.

Answer (score 2):

I think a solution is simpler. 
Replace all your missing values **" ?"** to **"?"** (no space). 
Use notepad++ or other text editor. Most of them have such a tool.

I checked this in Weka explorer. For values with space it doesn't recognize missing values.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file with notepad, replace (ctrl+H) replace all " ?" with "?" ( just delete the blank). It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

following steps solve the problem

1. Open the adult.data file using a text editor like notepad++
2. Remove the space in front of the '?'
3. Save the data file
4. Rename the data file in .csv format (like adult.csv)
5. Open the adult.csv file using Weka
6. Save the adult.csv file as a .arff file (this is an optional step)
7. Do necessary steps in data mining

Answer (score -3):

put "NaN" in the place of missing values .... it will work